# Where is the most appropriate place for posting DRBD questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Would this be the best place to post [DRBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Replicated_Block_Device) questions or is there another site specifically for DRBD questions?

Comment: There is a Slack channel for DRBD run by LINBIT, the company behind DRBD's lead developers. https://linbit.com/join-the-linbit-open-source-community/

Answer (score -5):

It depends. There's a mailing list run by the development company. See *[drbd-user -- General discussion](https://lists.linbit.com/listinfo/drbd-user)*.

OTOH, you're good here, too.

Comment: Question about DRBD are good here if and only if they are about programming. Questions about using DRBD are probably off-topic.